# PHP replacing a line from text file

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a canvas submitting a value to a hidden field in my html document.

```
<form name="hiddenStuff" method="post" onsubmit="return SubmitToDoc()" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="new" value="">
</form>
```

and I know the proper info is being stored in it because the javascript executes fine:

```
alert(submitInfo);
document.getElementById('new').value=submitInfo;
alert(document.getElementById('new').value);
document.forms['hiddenStuff'].submit();
```

this alerts the same info twice, so i know the info is stored in the value.

Anyways, I have the following function... It is not working properly. nothing gets changed in the text file.

```
function SubmitToDoc(){
    $content=$_POST['new'];
    $fileNameChallenge="challenge.txt";
        $file_handleChallenge=fopen($fileNameChallenge,"rw") or die("File won't open. Please contact the site administrator.");         
        $matchFound=FALSE;  
        while(!feof($file_handleChallenge) && !$matchFound){
            $lineChallenge=fgets($file_handleChallenge);
            $lineSplitChallenge=explode("\t",$lineChallenge,3);
            $lineSplitNEWChallenge=explode("\t",$content,3);
            if ($lineSplitNEWChallenge[0]==$lineSplitChallenge[0] && $lineSplitNEWChallenge[1]==$lineSplitChallenge[1])  {
                $matchFound=TRUE;
                file_put_contents($fileNameChallenge, $content);
            }
            }
    fwrite($file_handle,$content);
    fclose($file_handle);
}
```

the string that is currently in challenge.txt is, if that is any help (the line that it is replacing it with will be the same, except some numbers get changed).

```
mail1   mail2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: are you trying to call a PHP function from your `onsubmit`? That's impossible. PHP and Javascript execute at totally different times in totally different places. Or are the PHP and JS function names just coincidentally the same?

Comment: @marcB i can't seem to fix it.. have any ideas?